# Compiz - Move Window Controls to the Right

Tags: compiz, window-manager

I was wondering how I could move my window controls (close, minimize, maximize) to the right instead of the left. I have Ubuntu 14.04 with XFCE and Compiz. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04, I executed
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'` and it moved to the right for me.